# Can't delete VSO workspace using tf.exe

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to map a VSO account to a folder on this PC, and based on team conventions we have to map it to `C:\CompanyName` folder.

Now when I try to map it, Visual Studio complains that:

> The path C:\CompanyName is already mapped in workspace ComputerName;Windows Live ID\developerid

In previous instances of this error we would use `tf.exe` to remove the account like this:

```
tf workspaces

// showing list of workspaces, giving us the collection, workspace, owner, and computer

tf workspace /delete /collection:https://companyname.visualstudio.com workspace;owner
```

But it complains that:

> TF14061: The workspace Workspace;Owner does not exist

Is there any other way to delete all workspaces from a machine? This is truly a painful, frustrating process.

Comment: Did you try something like Attrice TFS sidekicks? That has an excellent workspace management utility.

Comment: I can't trust a tool that has died 2012. I rather map to a new workspace.

Answer (score 2):

When you delete a workspace, you should keep the owner same the it shows in `tf workspaces`.

Such as the ower name of a workspace is `Jim Green`, you should **keep the blank space** and quote the name with quotation marks, and delete the workspace by `tf workspace /delete /collection:https://account.visualstudio.com workspace;"Jim Green"`.

Below is an example:

```
C:\hello>tf workspaces
Workspace      Owner      Computer       Comment
-------------- ---------- -------------- --------------------------------------
mydev          marina liu computername

C:\hello>tf workspace /delete /collection:https://marinaliu.visualstudio.com mydev;"marina liu"
A deleted workspace cannot be recovered.
Workspace 'mydev;marina liu' on server 'https://marinaliu.visualstudio.com' has
0 pending change(s).
Are you sure you want to delete the workspace? (Yes/No) Yes
```

Comment: I tried that exactly. But it kept telling me that the workspace doesn't exist. That's a shame for Microsoft. We had to create another workspace and override our team conventions for this simple stupid reason.

Comment: If you still meet the issue, please also check if the workspace owner has  access to the TFVC repo now.

Comment: Permissions are taken away from the owner. But it makes no sense. Administrator should be able to delete an orphan workspace.

Comment: I can delete workspaces with different situation. Can you show the whole output of the command here?

Comment: It simply says that the specified workspace doesn't exist: `TF14061: The workspace WORKSPACE;Owner does not exist.`

Comment: I think the way to reproduce this is to add a user to your online Team Services account, let that user map some code to a workspace, then before deleting the workspace, remove the user from the account, and then try to map to the same location with the new user, which of course is not permitted, and then try to delete that workspace using `tf.exe /delete`.